# A configuration window is shown, every time I start Word?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2013

Every time I start Word 2007 , I get a configuration progress window as shown in the following screen shot . please any solution ?

I think this is happened when I installed Microsoft office 2013 and then uninstall it keeping my activated version of Microsoft office 2007.

[image]

Win7 32bits. I have installed office 2007 long time ago. I have a new office 2013 from my firm. I install it with keeping the old one. Then I uninstalled office 2013. The problem appears !

Comment: What have you attempted? Did you uninstall all Office Applications and reinstall? Have you researched anything?There are some key details missing, like what OS, is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: When you installed, then uninstalled 2013 it likely had replaced some of the Office system files. Now it is trying to fix it but can't. Try a repair install of Office 2007.

Comment: Repair install ?? Please how to do that ??

Comment: Go to `Control Panel > Uninstall a Program`, select your Office Suite and choose `Change`, then follow the prompts. You may need the install CD.

Comment: I have already tried this. Not working :(

Comment: That is an important detail you should include in your question. Try Francisco's answer below.

Comment: Ok i Will add it. Now i am connected from phone .... Thank u anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename a file called ID_00030.DPC in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12
```

for ID_00011.DPC

Or:
start > run

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

intro

Reference [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e14f498-485c-40c5-b522-d36d9b0c5697/office-2007-configuration-wizard-runs-every-time-i-start-any-application-word-excel-etc?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy)

> **UPDATED**

Comment: that's exactly what I did : I added DWORD key "NoReReg" with a value of "1" inside HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options.